# Convert Json date to java calendar

Tags: java, json, datetime, date-conversion

I have the following value  `/Date(1234043600000)/` in string type and I need to
convert it to java calendar type without a success,I have tried to use the following post and create date and than do something like the post

[How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

```
Date date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6))); 

and than do someting like

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

I got error in the  first line  since in the word date i have line in the middle and `substr(6)`   have error (The method substr(int) is undefined for the type String) ,how should I continue .

Thanks!

Comment: What is the compilation error you are geting?

Comment: You probably want to parse it to a long. And put an end index on your substring to not catch the final bracket.

Comment: @Thihara- sorry I cannot compile it since i have error."The method substr(int) is undefined for the type String"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in Java

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(jsonDate.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1")));
```

the problem with your example is that it's only good for javascript

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for you to get the number is to use

```
Long dateInMiliSeconds = new Scanner(jsonDate).nextLong();
Date date = new Date(dateInMiliSeconds);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Also the reason for your compilation error is that the method to get a sub string in Java `String` class is called `subString` not `substr`.

Although using the scanner is cleaner if you don't know much regex Evgeniy's answer may be better performance wise. I have no idea about the two approaches performance differences.

Comment: In the first Line I get dump