# convert Json Date with Offset to java date

Tags: java, json, datetime, odata

I have a Json date with offset. I need to convert that to java.

*Edm.DateTime*

```
"/Date(<ticks>["+" | "-" <offset>)/"

<ticks> = number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970

<offset> = number of minutes to add or subtract
```

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18121297/5783478) copied below, I am able to convert this date to Java. However, this does not takes into consideration the offset component. Is there any simpler way of resolving the offset.

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(jsonDate.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1")));
```

Below are some String dates that I am getting in the json date format

/Date(1463667774000+0400)/

/Date(1463667774000-5300)/

Program and result below

```
   str = "/Date(1463667774000-9000)/";
     date = new Date(Long.parseLong(str.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1")));
     System.out.println("1st "+ date);

      1st Thu May 19 19:52:54 IST 2016
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Can you post a few examples of the actual date values you have in your JSON?

Comment: @Mena: I have updated my question. pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on how to parse your custom dates.

```
// test value
String[] jsonDates = {"/Date(1463667774000-9000)/","/Date(1463667774000)/", "/Date(1463667774000+0400)/"};
//                          | preceded by "("
//                          |       | group 1: timestamp
//                          |       |    | optional group 2: "+" or "-"
//                          |       |    |      | optional group 3
//                          |       |    |      | (within group 2):    
//                          |       |    |      | minutes
//                          |       |    |      |       | followed by ")"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()(\\d+)(([-+])(\\d+))?(?=\\))");
for (String jsonDate: jsonDates) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(jsonDate);
    // matching pattern...
    if (m.find()) {
        // found: parsing timstamp
        long timestamp = Long.parseLong(m.group(1));
        Integer minutes = null;
        Boolean addOrSubstract = null;
        if (m.group(2) != null) {
            // parsing sign
            addOrSubstract = "+".equals(m.group(3)); 
            // parsing minutes
            if (m.group(4) != null) {
                minutes = Integer.parseInt(m.group(4));
            }
        }

        // initializing calendar
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(new Date(timestamp));
        // adding/removing minutes if parsed
        if (minutes != null) {
            c.add(
                Calendar.MINUTE, 
                addOrSubstract != null ? 
                (addOrSubstract ? minutes : -minutes) : 0
            );
        }
        Date date = c.getTime();
        System.out.println(date);
    }
    // not matched, different format
    else {
        // TODO error
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work for dates in json date format `/Date(1463667774000)/`. I have added handling for them in the else section. Thanks a lot

Comment: @mattymanme better to handle in the pattern and use conditionally. Let me try and edit my answer

Comment: Thank you. That would be great. :)

Comment: OK last amendment but stop changing the question please

Comment: hey.. The + and - was there in my first edit where I shared example formats... THanks for the edited answer.. :)